# Initialization of a reference versus initialization of an object

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I know dynamic casts works on pointers and references.
Both of the following work casting downwards

```
der d;
base& b = d;
der x = dynamic_cast<der&>(b);  -->A
der& y = dynamic_cast<der&>(b); -->B
x.method();
y.method();
```

I wanted to know what the difference is between A and B

Comment: You don't need any cast at all to convert from derived to base.

Comment: Let me change that - My emphasis is on the reference part

Comment: The difference between A and B doesn't involve `dynamic_cast` at all.  Are you asking what the difference is between a value type and a reference?

Comment: Still wrong. If `b` is an actual object, not a reference, the cast will always throw. Also, you've mixed up `der` vs `base` and `B` vs `A`, making it very confusing.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with `dynamic_cast`. Changed the title accordingly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "work"?

Comment: Fixed the example. Sorry didn't check the base object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
der x = dynamic_cast<der&>(b);
```

constructs an object of type `der` and initializes it with `dynamic_cast<der&>(b)`

The line

```
der& y = dynamic_cast<der&>(b);
```

just initializes a reference.

```
x.method();
```

calls `method()` on the separately constructed object.

```
y.method();
```

calls `method()` on the object `y` references, which is `d`.